# Addforce on the local Y axis of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gravity

I have a box, when I rotate the box the Y axis is always pointing out of the same side no matter which direction I rotate the box. This is good, I need this, but I need to rigidbody.addforce() -Y locally so the player has gravity no matter which way that side of the box is facing.

The one way I tried and thought it would work was to set the Ray of -Y on the box to the addforce but it's not doing anything.

I have tried everything I know of to do this but I can't seem to get this to work, any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: A little example code would be helpful.

Comment: If you have a local-space vector, you can convert it to world space by calling [`InverseTransformDirection`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html) on a transform component. For example, you could call `transform.InverseTransformDirection(-Vector3.up)` on the box. It's not clear from your question what vectors you actually have or need, though.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html

Will add a force relative to the rigidbody's direction.

You'll want to use

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.down * someGravityMultiplier);
}
```

This will move your character along its -y, its local downwards vector. Rather than the worlds downward vector. You should apply this force every **fixed** update.

Comment: Could you please improve this answer? Adding links to documentation would be helpful/